# How "perfect" does a database have to be?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm designing a website to track weight lifting and calories. I've never designed my own database before and I figured I should get is as spot on as possible before I start coding. Every time I think I'm done, I get antsy that it's not perfect. I've mostly fleshed it out in MySQL Workbench but I still have a few questions.

- How important is it to make the
  database "perfect" before hand? How
  hard is it to re-factor a database
  later?
- What does the engine option do? Right
  now all tables are defaulting to
  InnoDB engine? Any issues with this?
- Are dataypes changeable after data
  entry? Maybe not going from VARCHAR
  to INT, but what about VARCHAR(45) to
  VARCHAR(255)?
- What are basic database rules that **HAVE** to
  be followed for a successful design?

I've also attached my ERM diagram. If anyone could point out any obvious irregularities it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the diagram somewhere where it's readable?

Comment: @Tyler: Right-click on the image and open it directly. It's perfectly readable.

Comment: Its not hard to right click and view image -> http://i.imgur.com/Wz9GZ.png

Comment: Start as perfect as you can make it, then make it as imperfect as you need it.

Comment: @AgentConundrum This would qualify as an "upvotable" **answer**.

Comment: @Akinator: Your wish is my rep-whoring. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start as perfect as you can make it, then make it as imperfect as you need it.

Comment: As promised, +1, nothing wrong with selling some dignity once in a while for rep. Two up-votes besides mine! you owe me 20 ;) (and most voted answer!)

Comment: @Akinator: Heh, yeah. You failed to notice that your suggestion that I post this has resulted in me passing you in terms of rep. Thanks again. ;)

Comment: I this answer gets accepted I'll down-vote all you answers until were even! :)

Answer (score 3):

No practical, operating database is perfect.  They all have their warts.

One of the big advantages of using a database is that it can be built to withstand future change.  For example, use stored procedures for data updates and adding data.  If a table is eventually split, the stored procedure can be modified accordingly with no visible impact required for any external software.

If you wait until the design is perfect, you'll never get around to implementing anything useful.

Comment: Actually, all of _my_ databases _are_ perfect, but I'll give you +1 for that last sentence alone :-)

Answer (score 2):

In general, try to get your entities worked out, but adding fields, indexes, etc. after the fact is no big deal.  Refactoring entities to support different cardinalities is somewhat more involved.

At a glance, a couple things pop out...
1. All those numbered fields in your exercise table.  HUGE red flag.  I would refactor this right away.
2. badges->userbadges.  Even if you're enforcing a unique constraint on name, I would still make a new PK for that table (an id).
3. I would also take some time to normalize the naming of your id fields (i.e. in User, you use 'userid' but in food, you use 'id' instead of 'foodid').  Which way you go is a matter of choice but do try to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with a "perfect SQL database" is that SQL lacks the power to make a "perfect database" beyond a certain trivial level.

But, listen to your teachers and make Codd proud (3NF/BCNF and all that). It's a good bit easier to add caching or temporal un-normalized data later (for performance, when it's needed), etc, than it is to try and fix a database full of bad data. Data wants love. Love it.

That being said here are some thing I'll point out:

1. `exercise` looks *wrong, wrong, wrong* -- secondary1, secondary2, secondaryN ... no thanks! I would not leave the schema like this!
2. `userid` is a PK (varchar) but `usernumber` is an int? Again, no thanks. This doesn't appear to follow the same format as the other tables (most are `id`) and should be a tip-off that something may not be right. Perhaps the `userid` (or `username`?) should just have a unique constraint (you can add indexes to other columns too -- PKs generally "work best" with monotonically increasing values, although DBs should have a re-index schedule as well).
3. Inconsistent naming (`userid` vs `usernumber` vs `id`). No thanks. I don't care what you choose -- but please do it consistently.

Just my quick review.
Happy developing.

Comment: What would you suggest for number 1? Pulling the secondaries out into a separate table?

Comment: @Luminose Yes -- for an arbitrary lists it is generally much better to use a separate table in a relationship. However, something like 'AddressLine1', 'AddressLine2' (as seen in many order forms) is perfectly acceptable. The difference is subtle at times, but it does exist. I like to think of it being the difference between [heterogeneous] tuples and homogeneous lists.

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty good ... except your `exercise` table.  The `secondary1` to `secondary10` fields smack of something that should probably be in a different table.  However, you've done well everywhere else, so *maybe* this makes sense?  Think about it and make sure.

Perfectness doesn't matter, things can (and will) change after you're done.  Try to normalize down as far as you can (you've done this mostly already).  Field sizes can be changed, don't worry about that.

Comment: Breaks first normal form.  exercise should be one-to-many with secondary.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good advice has already been given.  Here's two more points to add:

1 - Never ever store a password in plain-text.  Salt it, hash it with a cryptographically secure hash, and store the salt/hash.

2 - Store date/time in UTC and convert to desired timezone at the presentation layer.  (I always store datetime as a unix timestamp, but that's just my preference.  Nothing wrong with the mysql DATETIME.)

I would recommend that you test your design before you fully commit to it, and write an entire application around it.  Push your design up to a real mysql database and and write a few quires to make sure you can add and retrieve all the info that you want.  Once you have your quires functioning write a script to load the database with lots(hundreds of thousandths to millions of records) and run your quires again.  This is the best way to test out your design. When you only have few hundred records, pretty much any query will be quick.  Once your database hits critical mass and no longer fits in ram you will you really be able to tell if your design and indexes are optimized for your intended use.

Answer (score 1):

Database change is to be expected, the question is how to manage it. Designing to at least Boyce-Codd / 5th Normal Form helps avoid in-built bias in the design and makes the schema easier to evolve when you have to.

Be careful about adding too much to the design before it is needed. If you design the schema too far ahead of the applications and other data consumers who use it then you will very possibly have to make more changes later. Apply the [YAGNI](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html) principle and apply [Agile](http://agilemanifesto.org/), iterative approaches to your project if you can.

During development I find that it makes sense to start by being as restrictive as possible with the schema and then ease those restrictions if you need to later. For instance if you aren't sure whether some business rule should always apply or not then it's better to enforce it anyway. It's easy to relax a constraint or make something optional later but once dependent code has been built it is much harder to implement new rules that the code was not designed to accommodate.

Be careful with the word "refactoring". Database schema changes generally alter the meaning and behaviour of the database. It may be a refactoring from the application point of view but as far as the database is concerned most schema change is functional rather than nonfunctional change.

Answer (score 1):

The perfect is the enemy of the good. The mediocre and the bad are also enemies of the good.

As others have said, learn how to normalize data.  At least up to BCNF.  Later, you can learn when to disregard the rules of normalization.

More generally, learn the relational model of data.  There are outstanding texts in this regard.  See CJ Date for starters.  Don't wait till you have learned the entire model to build your first database.

The relational model of data often leads to results that appear to mismatch with an object model of the same data.  Learn how to cope with this mismatch.

Be prepared to cope with change.

Answer (score 0):

1. I doubt that any database is perfect; don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good.
2. InnoDB enforces referential integrity to foreign keys.
3. Any ALTER can be done, but you might have to modify data in addition to tables.
4. Normalization rules, good indexing practices (e.g., one per WHERE clause), etc should be followed.

Comment: Just to add to #4... Normalisation is great, and helps in the long term, but in some cases speed ends up being a problem in fully normalised databases, and a little denormalisation goes a very long way to speeding things up.

Comment: @Mathew -- a little premature denormalisation can lock your system into a sub-optimal design!

Comment: What does "lock" mean?  That it can never be changed?  I don't think that's so.

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks pretty good!

The main thing now is to walk throw your use cases and user dialogs and see if all the flows are easily supported.

A perfect user experience is more important than a perfect DB.

Comment: James Anderson: "A perfect user experience is more important than a perfect DB". I can't say I agree. Ideally you want to get both database and the UX right of course. In the long term the risks and costs associated with bad data are generally far greater than the costs of a sub-standard UX. The application lasts only until the requirements change or the app is replaced. The data often lasts much, much longer. Getting the database right is at least as important and almost always *more* important than getting the UX right. In either case "perfection" is more often aspired to than achieved.

Comment: "A perfect user experience" is probably not achievable but a reasonable user experience -- as in you satisfy the business/user requirements in a reasonably elegant way -- means your system is fit for purpose and will survive long enough to accumulate enough data to make a poor data model a problem, a substandard user experience will probably mean the system is replaced long before an imperfect data model would be a problem.

Comment: You really think a "reasonable user experience" means your system is fit for purpose?! Yikes! It may be true that it will survive long enough to make the data model a problem. By that time good data may be irretrievably lost and your business may deservedly be facing lawsuits and financial loss as a result. You are much less likely to be sued for a poor user experience. Good UX is nice to have for sure - but good data is the lifeblood of any organisation.

Comment: First and foremost any succesful project will satisfy the business/user requirements. You may spend weeks perfecting a data model but if you dont pay attention to your stakeholders vision and there specific requirements your project will fail.

Comment: But you seemed to be implying that the right data model was outside the business requirement. If by "user experience" you mean all the business requirements (i.e. including the requirement to have a correct data model) then I think you need to rephrase your original comment: A perfect data model is an essential part of a perfect user experience.

Comment: According to ISO standards, UX means only "A person's perceptions and responses that result from the use and/or anticipated use of a product, system or service". The data model however is concerned with more than that. The need for an accurate data model also includes unanticipated requirements (the need for accurate data in the future) and regulatory, legal requirements as well. A responsible software professional's concern ought to extend beyond his immediate stakeholders.

Comment: So you would rather spend your time (and the businesses money) perfecting your data model and trying to cover every possible "what if" than actually doing what the business asked for. No wonder the businesses hate thier IT departments. :-) -- Its just a matter of priorities if you are going to obsess about getting something perfect then obsess about meeting the business goals,

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. A correct data model IS part of the proper goals of your business. You cannot expect your business customer to design the correct model for you. That is properly the resposibility of the database professional. I thought this was an interesting point though, so I've opened a new question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26906